# How to work with a DATE type in a COM/ATL project

Tags: c++, com, atl

I've got an ATL method that takes a DATE type, which is really a double. I can't find the class/functions for this type. Does anyone know how to operate on this type? I just need to make it into something I can get into boost::gregorian::date (yyyy/mm/dd). Also, I would really like to know what this double represents. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ATL use [`COleDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38wh24td%28VS.80%29.aspx) for `VT_DATE` variants.